# magento 2 documentation CRUD

Tags: magento, magento2, magento-2.3

I am learning Magento 2 after working on Symfony.

I'm desperate because I can't find the official Magento documentation explicit.
There has been a lot of change between Magento 2 to Magento 2.3.5 and it seems to go in the right direction, but I can't find a documentation or a tutorial which respects all the new standards.
I may not be able to search the Magento documentation.

I am looking for documentation concerning the relationship between entity and the dbb.

Can someone help me?
As I have just started I would like not to learn deprecated things.

Comment: check this link --- https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/how-to-create-crud-model-magento-2.html

Comment: Thank you, I used this tutorial, but for example from the start it talks about InstallSchema and the Magento doc indicates that it is an element that will be obsolete.
So is it updated regularly?